# Streaming a mp4 file to a television with UPNP/DLNA

Tags: video, stream, upnp, dlna

I have a Vizio TV (E470i-A0) that I'd like to discover and stream videos hosted online to.  I've been researching the UPNP protocol a bit to see if it would be possible to accomplish this.  Is this possible with UPNP or does the file have to be hosted on a UPNP server?

So far I've tried discovering all UPNP devices on my network with:
"M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n
HOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\n
MAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\n
ST:ssdp:all\r\n
MX:3\r\n\r\n"

However, I was unable to get a response from the Vizio TV with that.  I tried to monitor network traffic to see how a youtube video could cast to the TV and found that if i changed the ST value from "ssdp:all" to "urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1" I would get more information and could eventually find the apps that were installed on the television.  I looked into the DIAL protocol a little bit but wasn't sure that was what I was looking for (unless there is an app that can take mp4 URLs and play them).

Does anyone know why my tv wouldn't respond to ssdp:all but would to the DIAL query.  Is there a better way to accomplish my streaming goal or is UPNP the way to go?